# Cloud9 with Ruby on rails doesn't send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, cloud9-ide

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to send emails through Ruby on Rails on the Cloud9 IDE however I am not receiving any even though it says it was successful.

```
Rendered invitation_mailer/invitation_email.html.erb (1.0ms)
Emailing invitation to example@example.com

InvitationMailer#invitation_email: processed outbound mail in 18.2ms
```

Is there a special configuration that I need to apply to Cloud9 to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note that ports 25, 587, and 465 are blocked from Cloud9 to the outside. Please try to run your mail server on a port like 2587.